# How to avoid cleaned_data for each field if I have too many fields in the form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this view, i need to set predio_id to a default value, but the other fields the user has to fill it, problem is there are too many fields in the form, how can i save all the fields without write a cleaned_data for each field?

```
class ProductorPropietarioView(FormView):
    form_class = FormPropietario
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'productores/propietario.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        predio = Persona()
        predio.predio_id = 1
        predio.primer_nombre = form.cleaned_data['primer_nombre']
        predio.save()
        return super(ProductorPropietarioView,self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class FormPropietario(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Persona
        exclude = ("predio",)
```

Comment: You use a model form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, i have edited my question with the Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `form.save()`.

```
    predio = form.save(commit=False)
    predio.predio_id = 1
    predio.save()
```